# Type '}ckage' is not known on line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongo.list

Tags: apt, updates, software-center

I want to reinstall software center as I cannot open in. I used this command

`sudo apt-get update && apt-get install --reinstall software-center`

but this shows this-

`E: Type '}ckage' is not known on line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongo.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a typo in a configuration file (/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongo.list)

Since that is a third party repository configuration file you can resolve the problem by deleting that file, and then adding back the third party repository in question, or you can fix the typo by hand.

To delete the file:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongo.list
```